# Making select box a required field in some situations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form which has a select box with categories. If a particular category is selected, another select box/dropdown is displayed to the user. I need this second dropdown to be a required field when this category is selected.

I cannot add `validates :course, :presence => {:message => 'Course cannot be blank.'}` to the model because this field is not always required, I need some other way to make it required only when certain category is selected in the first dropbox.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `if` argument to `validates`, like this:

```
validates :course, :presence => {:message => "Course cannot be blink."}, :if => Proc.new { |u| u.first_dropdown_value == 'value_that_you_validate_courses_for' }
```

For more information, check out the [Rails documentation on conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation).

Comment: the first select box sets the value for privacy_level. I have added the following:
validates :course_id, :presence => {:message => "Course cannot be blank."}, :if => Survey.new { |u| u.privacy_level == 1} but I get the following error: undefined method `validate' for #<Survey:0x00000003b92230>

Comment: use `:if => Proc.new {|s| s.privacy_level == 1}`. Also check out [using a symbol with :if and :unless](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless), which might make the code cleaner if it gets longer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with Proc. Sorry about that. THanks for your help!